# Plot histogram using Python with different colors for positive and negative values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I did the following plot using Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist([x*100 for x in relativeError], bins = 100)
plt.xlabel("Relative Error [%]")
plt.ylabel("#samples")
plt.axvline(x=0, linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='grey')
```

[image]

But what I really want is to have different colors depending on whether the value is positive or negative.

Comment: You need to ceate 2 subplots. Split your positive values to one array, negatives - to second. Then generate individually histogramms (subplots) for each of this 2 arrays, using desired `facecolor=color_name` for each. Then combine this sublots to single plot.

Comment: @rocker996 provide sample data

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=jmpHCj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to compute the heights and positions of the bars for the histogram. Then, you you need to create a mask to filter the positive and negative data. Finally, you plot each of the subset of bars separately, and you set the colour at each call of the function `plt.bar()`.

Example with fake data that looks like yours:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate fake data
N = 1000
data = np.random.normal(loc=-1, size=N) # with average -1

n_bins = 100
heights, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=n_bins) # get positions and heights of bars

bin_width = np.diff(bins)[0]
bin_pos = bins[:-1] + bin_width / 2

plt.figure()

mask = (bin_pos >= 0)

# plot data in two steps
plt.bar(bin_pos[mask], heights[mask], width=bin_width, color='C1')
plt.bar(bin_pos[~mask], heights[~mask], width=bin_width, color='C0')

plt.xlabel("Relative Error [%]")
plt.ylabel("#samples")
plt.axvline(x=0, linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='grey')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can just colorize the bars after the fact.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(-20, 15, 5000)

_, _, bars = plt.hist(x, bins = 100, color="C0")
for bar in bars:
    if bar.get_x() > 0:
        bar.set_facecolor("C1")
plt.xlabel("Relative Error [%]")
plt.ylabel("#samples")
plt.axvline(x=0, linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='grey')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If instead you want to plot a bar chart of the histogrammed values (like the other answer suggests), it would rather look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(-20, 15, 5000)

hist, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=100)

colors = np.array(["C0", "C1"])[(edges[:-1] > 0).astype(int)]
plt.bar(edges[:-1], hist, width=np.diff(edges), align="edge", color=colors)
plt.xlabel("Relative Error [%]")
plt.ylabel("#samples")
plt.axvline(x=0, linestyle='--',linewidth=1, color='grey')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a fake dataset
height = [3, 12, 5, 18, 45]
bars = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
```

Now let’s study 3 examples of color utilization:

Uniform color using RGB
    RGB is a way of making colors. You have to to provide an amount of red, green and blue + the transparency and it returns a color.

```py
      plt.bar(y_pos, height, color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
      plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
      plt.show()
```